# Select limited amount of checkboxes and make the rest checkboxes disabled in Vue and Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am working on a project which is made in laravel 10 and Vue3.
In the form the users can only select 3 checkboxes and after that all checkboxes should get disabled.

I have tried it in this way as you can see below. But the problem is after 3 selected checkboxes all checkboxes are disabled, even the ones which are selected, so I can not deselect the selected ones.

How can I solve the problem?

```
<div class="form-group group-sm offset-top-20">
  <div v-if="professions_data !== null" v-for="(profession, index) in professions_data" 
 :key="profession.id">
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox d-inline-block" style="width:350px">
     <input class="custom-control-input" :id="profession.name_slug + '-' + profession.id"
     name="profession"
     :value="profession.id"
     v-model="value"
     type="checkbox"
     @change="updateField"
     :disabled="value.length > max && value.indexOf(n) === -1" >
      
     <label class="custom-control-label" :for="profession.name_slug + '-' + rofession.id">{{ profession.name }}</label>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

```
 data() {
        return {
            name: 'profession',
            professions_data: null,
            value: [],
            max:3
        }
    },
methods: {
        updateField() {
            this.clearErrors(this.name);
            this.$emit('update:field', this.value)
        },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a computed value to hold an array of the inactivated values (or an empty array if none). Something like:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'

const checkBoxData = ref([
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
]);
const mySelected = ref([]);
const inactivated = computed(() => {
    if (mySelected.value.length >= 3) {
        return checkBoxData.value.filter(cbd => !mySelected.value.includes(cbd));
    } else {
        return [];
    }
});

const disabled = (datum) => {
    return inactivated.value.includes(datum);
}
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <div
            v-for="chkboxDatum in checkBoxData"
            :key="chkboxDatum"
        >
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                id="chkboxDatum"
                v-model="mySelected"
                :value="chkboxDatum"
                :disabled="disabled(chkboxDatum)"
            >
            <label for="chkboxDatum">{{ chkboxDatum }}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        My Selected: {{ mySelected }}
    </div>
    <div>
        inactivated: {{ inactivated }}
    </div>
</template>
```

## Explanation

In this example the data is simple:

```
const checkBoxData = ref([
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
]);
```

I create a ref to hold the selected values:

```
const mySelected = ref([]);
```

and then a computed property that I called `inactivated` to hold the data points that I want to be inactivated. It should return an array, initially an empty array if the number of selected items is less than 3, but as soon as 3 items have been selected, it returns all the remaining values:

```
const inactivated = computed(() => {
    if (mySelected.value.length >= 3) {
        return checkBoxData.value.filter(cbd => !mySelected.value.includes(cbd));
    } else {
        return [];
    }
});
```

Then this function can be used by the checkbox edit item to determine if it should be inactivated or not:

```
const disabled = (datum) => {
    return inactivated.value.includes(datum);
}
```

---

## Options API

Here is a similar example, but one that uses the Options API, which you appear to be using:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div
            v-for="(profession, index) in professions_data"
            :key="profession.id"
        >
            <input
                :id="profession.name_slug + '-' + profession.id"
                name="profession"
                :value="profession.id"
                v-model="value"
                type="checkbox"
                :disabled="inactivateProfession(profession)"
            >
            <label :for="profession.name_slug + '-' + profession.id">{{ profession.name }}</label>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
            Value: {{ value }}
        </div>
        <div>
            inactivatedProfessions: {{ inactivatedProfessions }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    computed: {
        inactivatedProfessions() {
            if (this.value.length >= this.max) {
                return this.professions_data.filter(pd => !this.value.includes(pd.id)).map(p => p.id);
            } else {
                return [];
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        inactivateProfession(profession) {
            return this.inactivatedProfessions.includes(profession.id);
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            // make professions_data an array
            professions_data: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name_slug: "doctor",
                    name: "Doctor",
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name_slug: "lawyer",
                    name: "Lawyer",
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name_slug: "businessman",
                    name: "Businessman",
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    name_slug: "salesman",
                    name: "Salesman",
                },
                {
                    id: 5,
                    name_slug: "ballplayer",
                    name: "Ballplayer",
                },
                {
                    id: 6,
                    name_slug: "druggist",
                    name: "Druggist",
                },
                {
                    id: 7,
                    name_slug: "mailmain",
                    name: "Mailmain",
                },
                {
                    id: 8,
                    name_slug: "policeman",
                    name: "Policeman",
                },
                {
                    id: 9,
                    name_slug: "politician",
                    name: "Politician",
                },
                {
                    id: 10,
                    name_slug: "fireman",
                    name: "Fireman",
                },
            ],
            value: [],
            max: 3
        };
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

i made you a working example.
See here: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-y82jpc?file=src%2FApp.vue&terminal=dev)

but this is the code:

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="checkbox in checkboxes">
    <label :for="checkbox.label">{{ checkbox.label }}</label>
    <input
      :name="checkbox.label"
      type="checkbox"
      :checked="checkbox.isChecked"
      :disabled="handleCheckboxDisabledState(checkbox.isChecked)"
      @click="checkbox.isChecked = !checkbox.isChecked"
    />
  </div>
  MaxCheckable: {{ checkSelectedCount }}
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, computed } from 'vue';

// Ignore this. Just created to create Checkboxes.
function createCheckboxes(amount) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= amount; i++) {
    const checkboxItem = {
      isChecked: false,
      label: `checkbox-${i}`,
    };
    checkboxes.value.push(checkboxItem);
  }
}

function handleCheckboxDisabledState(checkbox) {
  // only triggers if the maximum amount of checkboxes are set and if the actuall checkbox is not checked allready.
  // makes you able to toggle the checkbox back to uncheck after limit has been reached.
  return !checkbox && checkSelectedCount.value >= maxPossibleSelected.value;
}

// sets your amount of how many checkboxes are allowed to check before all others become "disabled"
// this doesnt needs to be a "ref" if this is not dynamic
const maxPossibleSelected = ref(3);

// should have your actuall checkboxes.
const checkboxes = ref([]);

// check for "how many checkboxes are checked already" so you can toggle the others "disabled" when reached max.
const checkSelectedCount = computed(
  () => checkboxes.value.filter((checkbox) => checkbox.isChecked).length
);

// Ignore the entire "onMounted". Just created to create checkboxes.
onMounted(() => {
  createCheckboxes(10);
});
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Written in Vue3 Composition API

Comment: Please give your answer some decent explanation so that I can up-vote it. As written, it is little more than a code dump, but with explanation, it can be helpful to future visitors. Thanks.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, you are absolutely right. i have added comments inside the code and refactored a little bit for better readability.

Comment: That helps. Note that from my experience, it is also good to have some explanatory text in the answer as plain text that is separate from the code, but your milage may vary. 1+